# JSON QUERY parse tip

Tags: json, debugging, select, jq

just want to get some expert tips on you on how to grab only this from AutoScalingGroups:

> awseb-e-ASG

Actual JSON Output

```
{
"EnvironmentResources": {
    "EnvironmentName": "MY-APP",
    "AutoScalingGroups": [
        {
            "Name": "awseb-e-ASG"
        }
    ],
    "Triggers": [],
    "LoadBalancers": [
        {
            "Name": "awseb-e-ELB"
        }
    ],
    "Queues": [],
    "Instances": [
        {
            "Id": "i-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXd"
        }
    ],
    "LaunchConfigurations": [
        {
            "Name": "awseb-e-LAUNCH"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I tried several commands but only getting this:

```
jq -r ".EnvironmentResources.LaunchConfigurations"

[
 {
  "Name": "awseb-e-ASG"
 }
]


jq -r ".EnvironmentResources.LaunchConfigurations.Name"
jq: error: Cannot index array with string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awseb-e-ASG` is under .AutoScalingGroups

so you could use the following filter:

```
.EnvironmentResources.AutoScalingGroups[].Name
```

### Debugging

It usually pays to pay attention to the error message:

> jq: error: Cannot index array with string

This, in effect, is telling you that `.LaunchConfigurations.Name` is erroneous because .LaunchConfigurations is an array, and therefore cannot have a string-valued key.